# JDOM: Convert Content to Document

Tags: java, xml, dom, jdom

I tried to cast a Content variable to Document:

```
(Document)document
```

and got "Cannot cast from Content to Document".  also tried:

```
new Document(document))
```

but got: "the constructor Document(Content) is undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`getDocument()`](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Content.html#getDocument()) method to get the document that owns a given `Content` object.

```
document.getDocument()
```

However, note that these are two different concepts. A `Document` is *never* a `Content`, nor is the reciprocal true. A `Document` object represents an entire XML document, but `Content` represents an actual node. You can get the root node of a document using [`getRootElement()`](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Document.html#getRootElement()).